# Add-on Dev: Label Tool-tips?

Tags: scripting, add-on, development

I have a list of 12 'elements', where several check-boxes will relate to each element. The best way I can think of to handle this type of situation is to draw the check-boxes without labels, then manually draw the label on the left side of them, with header labels over the boxes:

```
        X    Y    Z
  One: [ ]  [ ]  [ ]
  Two: [ ]  [ ]  [ ]
Three: [ ]  [ ]  [ ]
```

But I would like to show information about an element when the user hovers the label. Is it possible to do something like this? Maybe I can draw the text as something other than labels to achieve this?

Appreciate any advice